# Multiple key names with same value inside

Tags: javascript, csv, object

I'm trying to make a Javascript script that should parse multiple CSV file (with papaparse) and then merge all that data in one output CSV file.
I will use csv-writer for write the output file but that file should be like that :

```
ID : idnumber1
Header1 Header2 Header3
value1 value2 value3
ID: idnumber2
Header1 Header2 Header3
value1 value2 value3
```

I don't know how to write the ID before the header, so I thought to modify the input object like that :

```
    {
      ID : idnumber1
       [
         Header1 : value1,
         Header2 : value2,
         Header3 : value3
       ],
      ID : idnumber2
       [
         Header1 : value1,
         Header2 : value2,
         Header3 : value3
       ]
    }
```

Someone could tell me if my idea is right and how create an object like that? Thanks!

Comment: If the order is important, you should probably store a list of objects.

Comment: how can I do that? sorry but I'm new on that. Thanks

Comment: Added an example of how to structure each file and how to iterate over a list of files. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this, to easily be able to iterate over the rows/columns, with order preserved

```js
const file1 = {
  id: 'idnumber1',
  rows: [
    ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3'],
    ['Value1', 'Value1', 'Value1'],
  ],
 };

const file2 = {
  id: 'idnumber1',
  rows: [
    ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3'],
    ['Value1', 'Value1', 'Value1'],
  ],
};

const allFiles = [file1, file2];

allFiles.forEach((file) => {
  console.log('id: %s', file.id);
  file.rows.forEach( row => console.log(...row));
});
```

Comment: Can I use just one "file1" and repeat id and rows field or I have to make another "file2"?

Comment: I would try to create the allFiles structure, so that you have an order of both "files" and rows per "file"